# Repository Event Handler is not getting invoked after a cascade delete

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, event-handling, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two Classes. The first is `Advertisement` and the second is `Image` . The Advertisement class contain a list of images. This list is annotated with:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

I wont to run do some actions (delete an image from the server) when an image is deleted from database. I don't call image repository to delete images there are deleted when deleting an Advertisement by cascade. I create a repository event handler:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(Image.class)
public class ImageEventHandler {

@Autowired
ImageStorageService imageStorageService;

@HandleAfterDelete
public void handleImageAfterDelete(Image image){
    String imageName = image.getName();
    System.out.println("**********************************");
    imageStorageService.deleteFile(imageName);
}
}
```

My event handler is not called at all when deleting an image .

Any idea about what could be the problem.

Comment: maybe you should try in `handleAfterDeleteAdvertisement`  to invoke `handleImageAfterDelete` for each element of  imageList ?

Answer (score 0):

I also have had problems with EventHandler in the past. My mistake was, not to create the corresponding bean, described here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Maybe this is your problem, too.

Greetings Matthias

Comment: what do you mean by creating the corresponding bean.

Comment: You can create a Bean, or use @Component on class level. Spring needs a possibility to find the EventHandler, for this you need a bean. Therefore you can create it by you own, or use annotations which create one, for example the component annotation.

Comment: I added @Component to  ImageEventHandler class still don't work